# Filling a row and columns of a ndarray with a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, numpy, for-loop

I'm starting with Python and I have a basic question with "for" loop
I have two array which contains a values of a same variables:

```
    A = data_lac[:,0]
```

In the first array, I have values of area and in the second on, values of mean depth.
I would like to find a way to automatize my calculation with different value of a parameter. The equation is the following one:

```
    g= (np.sqrt(A/pi))/n
```

Here I can calculte my "g" for each row. Now I want to have a loop with differents values of "n". I did this:

```
    i=0
    while i <= len(A)-1:
      for n in range(2,6):
        g[i] = (np.sqrt(A[i]/pi))/n
        i += 1
    break
```

In this case, I just have one column with the calculation for n = 2 but not the following one. I tried to add a second dimension to my array but I have an error message saying that I have too many indices for array.

In other, I would like this array:

```
    g[len(A),5]
```

g has 5 columns each one calculating with a different "n"

Any tips would be very helpful,
Thanks

Update of the code:

```
    data_lac=np.zeros((106,7))
    data_lac[:,0:2]=np.loadtxt("/home...", delimiter=';', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1))
    data_lac[:,1]=data_lac[:,1]*0.001

    #Initialisation
    A = data_lac[:,0]
    #example for A with 4 elements
    A=[2.1, 32.0, 4.6, 25]

    g = np.zeros((len(A),))
```

Comment: Notice that if your A has length of 2 (example) you will try to access A[4] in the for loop -> which cause to Error - that happens because you increment i in the for loop and ignore the check you makes in the upper while loop

Comment: If i understand you well, there is a conflict between both loops as i'm not checking the condition of my "while" loop?

Comment: That why you getting out of bound in your array. Do you expect G to be 2-dim array with dim of (len(A), 5)?

Comment: Ok I understand! Yes exactly, with the rows corresponding to each different n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you share the indexes within both loops. You were increasing the i (index for the upper while loop) inside the inner for loop (which index with n).

I guess you have A (1 dim array) and you want to produce G (2 dim array) with size of (Len(A, 5))

I am not sure I'm fully understand your require output but I believe you want something like:

```
i=0
while i <= len(A)-1:
  for n in range(2,6):
    g[i][n-2] = (np.sqrt(A[i]/pi))/n    # n-2 is to get first index as 0 and last as 4
  i += 1     # notice the increace of the i is for the upper while loop
break
```

**Important** - remember that in python **indentation** means a lot -> so make sure the `i +=1` is under the while scope and not indent to be inside the for loop

Notice - G definition should be as:

```
g = np.zeros((len(A),4), dtype=float)
```

The way you define it (without the 4) cause it to be 1 dim array and not 2-dim

Comment: Thanks for the help, your guess is right, I want to calculate different value of G depending on the "n". I tried your solution but I still have an Error: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment. Maybe this is linked with the array g which might be written like that:           g[[i],[n-2]] ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with python but how did you define G? it should be something like: G = [[0 for x in range(len(A))] for y in range(2,6)]

Comment: I would say the same. I define G as a 2D array

Comment: Can you please update the question with more of your code (including the G definition and example of the A array content) -> the script I wrote runs fine

Comment: Update the answer - with the 4 in g definitain it is working for me with your example input